# Remove Double Quotes From begining and END

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to remove the double quotes from begining and end of the result. These double quotes are appended automatically.

I am getting a result like:

```
"['abc',123],['qwe',234],['dfg',423]"
```

I need to pass this result as

```
['abc',123],['qwe',234],['dfg',423]
```

without double quotes.

Note: Getting this result from ajax Call as `html` datatype and content type as `application/json;charset=utf-8` and I am getting these double quotes as it is returning string. How to remove those.

Is there any way that I can take the result in an array and then can remove the string like:

> var ajaxData = result;

Now the ajaxData is having the result as

> ```
> ["['abc',123],['qwe',234],['dfg',423]"]
> ```

now can be apply remove or replace double quotes?

Comment: It looks like string manipulation is *not* what you should do here. Do you see the quotes in the body of the request answer ? Or only in the console ?

Comment: @Rohit Jain try `JSON`datatype instead of `html`

Comment: The quotes look like an artifact of representation in your browser. Just try `var arr = JSON.parse('['+data+']')`

Comment: I assume you'll still need to parse the stuff inside quotes and it isn't JSON so you cannot use a regular JSON parser. It's a pretty rare backend code—any chance to just fix that instead?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Not working!!!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I am working an google charts, and expecting a data in the format mentioned above. Any suggestion

Comment: @RohitJain - Your question doesn't seem to answer mine. What feedback do you want exactly? Do you mean that Google doesn't know how to generate JSON?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I was just explaining the question. I am expecting the result as html only, so I cannot change it to JSON. Now what I have is these double quotes which got generated automatically. Is their any way that these can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
function stripEndQuotes(s){
var t=s.length;
if (s.charAt(0)=='"') s=s.substring(1,t--);
if (s.charAt(--t)=='"') s=s.substring(0,t);
return s;
}
var str='"hello"';
str=stripEndQuotes(str);
alert(str);
```